# An iterator for reading a file byte by byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, iterator, byte

Is there an iterator for reading a file [byte by byte](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray)?

Comment: You can use file.read(1) to read a single character from a file. If you really need to this can be typecast to a byte.

Comment: it's pretty easy to read the file line-by-line, then iterate the characters in the line, though I know that's not exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an iterator for byte by byte but it is easier enough to create a generator to do it:

```
def bytefile(f):
    b = f.read(1)
    while b:
        yield b
        b = f.read(1)

with open('<file>', 'rb') as f:
    for b in bytefile(f):
        <do something>
```

But this really isn't very efficient, and it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) the file, if you're using *nix or Windows. This should be the *most* efficient way to iterate over the bytes of a file:

```
import mmap

with open('user.py', 'rb') as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for b in mm:
        print(b)
    mm.close()
```